# Efficient way of returning next N words & previous N words to display

Tags: java, android

I wish to allow the user to view a string, N words at a time. They can move both forwards and backwards, such that backwards will display the previous N words. Also, as we are limited by screen space, so I want to select only the words that will fit, up to n (whole words, no ...).

So, I created the initial not too pretty method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    static String text = "This is a dummny sentence. I am a dummy sentence two. This is dummy sentence 3. This is a dummy sentence";

    static int currentWordIndex = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nextWords = getNextWords(5, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        nextWords = getNextWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        nextWords = getNextWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        nextWords = getNextWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);


        String prevWords = getPreviousWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + prevWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        prevWords = getPreviousWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("PreviousSentence: " + prevWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        prevWords = getPreviousWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("PreviousSentence: " + prevWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        nextWords = getNextWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);

        nextWords = getNextWords(3, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        System.out.println("Index: " + currentWordIndex);


    }

    public static String getPreviousWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        ArrayList<String> initialSelection = new ArrayList();
        String[] splitWords = text.split(" ");
        int charCount = 0;
        int maxN = currentWordIndex - n;
        if(maxN < 0) {
            maxN = 0;
        }
        for (int i = maxN; i < currentWordIndex; i++) {
            if(i > splitWords.length) {
                break;
            }
            initialSelection.add(splitWords[i]);
            charCount += splitWords[i].length();
        }

        if (charCount > maxCharacterLength) {
            charCount = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < initialSelection.size(); x++) {
                if (initialSelection.size() == 0)
                    return null;
                initialSelection.remove(initialSelection.size() - 1);
                for (String s : initialSelection) {
                    charCount += s.length();
                }
                if (charCount <= maxCharacterLength) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : initialSelection) {
            sb.append(s + " ");
        }
        if(currentWordIndex - initialSelection.size() < 0) {
            currentWordIndex = 0;
        } else {
            currentWordIndex -= initialSelection.size();
        }
        return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length());
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the next n number of words given the maximum number of characters that can fit on the screen.
     * If not all words fit on the screen
     *
     * @param n                  number of words
     * @param maxCharacterLength of text that can fit on the screen.
     * @return next words
     */
    public static String getNextWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        ArrayList<String> initialSelection = new ArrayList();
        int charCount = 0;
        String[] splitWords = text.split(" ");
        int maxN = currentWordIndex + n;
        if (maxN > splitWords.length - 1) {
            maxN = splitWords.length - 1;
        }
        // add the words
        for (int i = currentWordIndex; i < maxN; i++) {
            if (i > splitWords.length - 1)
                break;
            initialSelection.add(splitWords[i]);
            charCount += splitWords[i].length();
        }

        // if there's too many, remove the last word until everything fits
        if (charCount > maxCharacterLength) {
            charCount = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < initialSelection.size(); x++) {
                if (initialSelection.size() == 0)
                    return null;
                initialSelection.remove(initialSelection.size() - 1);
                for (String s : initialSelection) {
                    charCount += s.length();
                }
                if (charCount <= maxCharacterLength) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // add back into a string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : initialSelection) {
            sb.append(s + " ");
        }

        // update the index/pivot based on the words selected
        if (currentWordIndex + initialSelection.size() < splitWords.length - 1) {
            currentWordIndex += initialSelection.size();
        } else {
            currentWordIndex = splitWords.length;
        }
        return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length());
    }

}
```

Which gives this output:

```
Next Sentence: One two three four five. 
Index: 5
Next Sentence: Six Seven Either, 
Index: 8
Next Sentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven. 
Index: 11
Next Sentence: Twelve thirdteen fourteen 
Index: 14
Previous Sentence: Twelve thirdteen fourteen 
Index: 11
PreviousSentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven. 
Index: 8
PreviousSentence: Six Seven Either, 
Next Index: 5
Next Sentence: Six Seven Either, 
Index: 8
Next Sentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven. 
Index: 11
```

Which is incorrect. It appears the next and previous is working - just not when changing between them. It should say:

```
Next Sentence: One two three four five. 
Index: 5
Next Sentence: Six Seven Either, 
Index: 8
Next Sentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven. 
Index: 11
Next Sentence: Twelve thirdteen fourteen 
Index: 14
Previous Sentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven.
Index: 11
PreviousSentence: Six, Seven, Either. 
Index: 8
PreviousSentence: three four five, 
Index: 5
Next Sentence: Six Seven Either, 
Index: 8
Next Sentence: Nine, Ten, Eleven. 
Index: 11
```

I understand what the problem is: after the getNext" increments, it sets the marker at the begining of the next sentence. Thus when 'getPrevious" is called, it calls, the last sentence (the current one already on display).

So I suppose the solution would be to have both a beginning and end marker - marking the start and end of the sentence indexs.

But i'm wondering if anyone has a more elegant solution so solving this issue?

Comment: It would be easiest if you split the string once and wrapped using `Arrays.asList(array)`, and then just used `List.sublist` to extract the slice of words you want.

Comment: @AndyTurner that would certainly neaten this up.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want, can you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to get it working with @mithat konuk solution. But I think it's likely better with sublists.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.createTokens();
        String nextWords = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
        String nextWords2 = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords2);
        String nextWords3 = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords3);

        String previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + previousWords);
        previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + previousWords);
        previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + previousWords);
        previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + previousWords);
        previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Previous Sentence: " + previousWords);

        nextWords = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
    }


    static String text = "I am a cat who sat on a mat and yelled as someone who was fat";

    private static List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    // index of the start of the next sentence (i.e also the end of the sentence that is currently being displayed)
    static int nextWordIndex = 0;
    // index of the first word of the current sentence being displayed.
    static int firstWordIndex = 0;

    public void createTokens() {
        String[] splitWords = text.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
            list.add(splitWords[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getPreviousWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int characterCount = 0;
        int itemSize = 0;
        // you need to check this negative or not
        if(firstWordIndex < 0)
            firstWordIndex = 0;
        ListIterator<String> nextIter = list.listIterator(firstWordIndex);
        while (nextIter.hasPrevious() && itemSize < n) {
            String elem = (String) nextIter.previous();
            characterCount += elem.length();
            if (characterCount > maxCharacterLength) {
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.insert(0, elem + " ");
            itemSize++;
        }

        if(firstWordIndex == 0) {
            firstWordIndex = 0;
            nextWordIndex = itemSize;
        }
        nextWordIndex = firstWordIndex;
        firstWordIndex-=itemSize;

        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the next n number of words given the maximum number of characters
     * that can fit on the screen. If not all words fit on the screen
     *
     * @param n
     *            number of words
     * @param maxCharacterLength
     *            of text that can fit on the screen.
     * @return next words
     */
    public String getNextWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int characterCount = 0;
        int itemSize = 0;
        ListIterator<String> nextIter = list.listIterator(nextWordIndex);
        while (nextIter.hasNext() && itemSize < n) {
            String elem = (String) nextIter.next();
            characterCount += elem.length();
            if (characterCount > maxCharacterLength) {
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.append(elem);
            strBuilder.append(" ");
            itemSize++;
        }
        firstWordIndex = nextWordIndex;
        nextWordIndex+=itemSize;
        return strBuilder.toString();

    }
}
```

Output:

> Sentence: I am a cat who  Sentence: sat on a mat and  Sentence: yelled
>   as someone who was  Previous Sentence: a mat and  Previous Sentence:
>   who sat on  Previous Sentence: am a cat  Previous Sentence: I 
>   Previous Sentence:  Sentence: I am a cat who

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 public class Test {

    static String text = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen";

    static int currentWordIndex = 0;
    private static List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void createTokens() {
        String[] splitWords = text.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
            list.add(splitWords[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getPreviousWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int characterCount = 0;
        int item_size = 0;
        // you need to check this negative or not
        currentWordIndex = currentWordIndex - n; 
        ListIterator<String> nextIter = list.listIterator(currentWordIndex);
        while (nextIter.hasPrevious() && item_size < n) {
            String elem = (String) nextIter.previous();
            characterCount += elem.length();
            if (characterCount > maxCharacterLength) {
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.append(elem);
            strBuilder.append(" ");
            item_size++;
        }

        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the next n number of words given the maximum number of characters
     * that can fit on the screen. If not all words fit on the screen
     *
     * @param n
     *            number of words
     * @param maxCharacterLength
     *            of text that can fit on the screen.
     * @return next words
     */
    public String getNextWords(int n, int maxCharacterLength) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int characterCount = 0;
        int item_size = 0;
        ListIterator<String> nextIter = list.listIterator(currentWordIndex);
        while (nextIter.hasNext() && item_size < n) {
            String elem = (String) nextIter.next();
            characterCount += elem.length();
            if (characterCount > maxCharacterLength) {
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.append(elem);
            strBuilder.append(" ");
            item_size++;
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();

    }

}
```

App.java

```
    public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.createTokens();
            String nextWords = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
            System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords);
            String nextWords2 = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
            System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords2);
            String nextWords3 = t.getNextWords(5, 30);
            System.out.println("Sentence: " + nextWords3);

            String previousWords = t.getPreviousWords(5, 30);
            System.out.println("Sentence: " + previousWords);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sentence: one two three four five
Sentence: six seven eight nine ten 
Sentence: eleven twelve thirteen fourteen 
Sentence: ten nine eight seven six
```

Comment: Don't post a suggestion as an answer

Comment: It would still have the same issue because even if I iterate through hasNext and hasPrev. hasPrev = hasNext whenever there is a switch in direction. Meaning, still to keep track of both initial and last index of text on display. Not really a big issue I guess.

Comment: I have been posted comment in code u need to check this line

Comment: Output: 

Sentence: one two three four five 
Sentence: one two three four five 
Sentence: one two three four five

Comment: Missing:         currentWordIndex+=item_size;
in getNext.. :)

Output: Sentence: one two three four five 
Sentence: six seven eight nine ten 
Sentence: eleven twelve thirteen fourteen 
Previous Sentence: eleven ten 
Previous Sentence: eight seven 

Previous sentence still incorrect. Hmm..

Comment: Good to hear u found i did not much tested 

Comment: Aye it encounters issues with previous still. Notice it misses out the "9" ? This is because of the currentWordIndex - n; (when it may not always decrease by n numbers if there is a small amount of characters allowed, may only decrease by 1). But i'll see if I can write another solution using iterators.